# How to get functions from a python file without import

Tags: python, function, class

I'm making a program that detects python files and reads their classes and functions for then to be called. How do I list the functions from another python file without importing it? and how do I call them?

Structure of the program:

- Index.py (main py file)
- /Content

  - /Modules

    - Modules.py
    - ChickenModule.py (module I want to get functions from)

Modules.py list all the python files from /Modules and stores them on a list.
Index.py calls the functions in Modules.py (Just to keep things less messy)

ChickenModule.py has a Class named ChickenStuff that prints "I'm a chicken" whenever it's `self.(something)` called.

The goal of the program is for the user to be able to put .py files in modules and when running index.py the functions and classes of said .py files will be listed.

Comment: Why do you want to do this without `import`ing them? That would be the standard approach.

Comment: The goal of the program is to be able to put files into the Modules folder and the program to automatically read them.

Comment: `import` is the facility Python has defined for obtaining services and attributes from another module.  Why do you need to find another way to accomplish this?  `import` *is* how the program automatically reads them.

Comment: You're going to have to `import` them somehow to use what's defined in them.

Comment: @Norrius Tried that already

Comment: If that doesn't solve your problem, it's worth expanding on why in the question (you can always [edit] it). Right now the question doesn't make much sense, unfortunately.

Comment: @Norrius I added the goal of the program, let's see if that makes it more clear

Comment: I think I understand what you're trying to do, but I'd still say inspecting imports is not a good way here. If you're interested in classes that do something, you could define a base class and make your ChickenStuff derive from it. Then you can look at `__subclasses__` or (for example) register the subclasses, without tampering with the crazy machinery that is `importlib`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a built in library called `importlib` that might be what you need. I'm assuming that you want classes listed. You'll need `inspect` for this.

```py
import os
import os.path as path
import importlib
import inspect

# get a list of all files in Content/Modules
filelist = os.listdir("Content/Modules")

# import every file ending in .py
for fname in filelist:
  if path.splitext(fname)[1] == 'py':
    my_module = importlib.import_module(path.splitext(fname)[0]) # load the module
    for _, obj in inspect.getmembers(my_module): # iterate through members
      if isinstance(obj, type): # check if members is a class
        print(obj)
```

Comment: "You'll need inspect for this." no you don't. In python 3, simply `isinstance(obj, type)`

Comment: What if I want to list functions too?

Comment: @BigXKu use `if isinstance(obj, type) or isinstance(obj, function):` instead